# Optimization of a Markov сhain with symbolic transition rate

Tags: performance-tuning, probability-or-statistics, recursion, markov-chains, random-process

I am trying to work on 1D random walk that can move to left, right or stay with probabilities $p_i$,$q_i$,$r_i$ that changes with the site $i$. I am trying to simulate this by using a recurrence function with memoization:

```
    NN = 101;
 
R = Table[Subscript[x, i], {i, NN}];

p = Table[(1 - R[[i]])/2, {i, 1, NN}];

q = Table[(1 - R[[i]])/2, {i, 1, NN}];

P[t_, n_] := 
  P[t, n] = 
   p[[n - 1]] P[t - 1, n - 1] + q[[n + 1]] P[t - 1, n + 1] + 
    R[[n]] P[t - 1, n];

P[0, n_] := KroneckerDelta[n - (NN + 1)/2];
```

I need the transitions to be be symbolic because i am going later to relate the terms $r_i^n$ with $\langle r^n \rangle$ by doing the replacement:

```
rules = Flatten[
   Table[Table[Power[Subscript[x, i], m] -> N[r[m]], {m, 1, 100}], {i,
      1, NN}]];

P0 = Expand[FullSimplify[P[i, (NN + 1)/2]]];
bla = FullSimplify[P0 /. rules];
```

I only need to calculate the probability on the initial position. But this code is taking more than a day and it's only on $t = 11$ is there a better way to evaluate this?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simpler realization. We imagine a grid from -n..n. Then we create probabilities for every point and pack them in an association for easy access:

```
SeedRandom[1];
prob = Table[{t1 = RandomReal[{0, 1}], t2 = RandomReal[{0, 1 - t1}], 
    1 - t1 - t2}, 2 n + 1];
aprob = AssociationThread[Table[i, {i, -n, n}] -> prob];
```

Then we create the random path and draw it:

```
pos = 0;
path = NestList[(# + RandomChoice[aprob[#] -> {-1, 0, 1}]) &, 0, n];
c = 0;
Graphics[Line[{c++,#} & /@ path]]
```

[image]

Comment: But i need t1 and t2 to be symbolic...

Comment: Put everything in a function: fun[t1_,t22_]:=Module[...]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you want to do honestly.
if you want everything to be symbolic,how about using characteristic function?

Consider a conditional random walk.
Let's say that if the value of i is greater than or equal to ±2 and does not move any further.

```
cf = p1*Exp[-1*t] + q1*Exp[t] + r1*Exp[0*t];
cfupper = p2*Exp[-1*t] + r2*Exp[0*t];
cflower = q1*Exp[t] + r1*Exp[0*t];
terms = Table[Exp[m*t], {m, -2, 2}];
newcfs = 
  Table[i /. {i_ /; i <= -2 -> cflower, i_ /; i >= 2 -> cfupper, 
     i_ /; And[i < 2, i > -2] -> cf}, {i, -2, 2}];
multiply = newcfs*terms;
```

The transition probability depending on state i is expressed by dividing the next operator according to the position.

```
getcofs = 
  Function[{tgt}, 
   If[Head[#] === Integer, Coefficient[tgt, Exp[t], 0], 
      Coefficient[tgt, #]] & /@ terms];
```

This is the probability of each point (coefficient of Exp)

Let's do simulate.

```
steps = NestList[(getcofs[#] . multiply // Expand) &, cf, 30];
```

```
ff = getcofs /@ steps[[;; 10]];
ff[[5]]

{15 p1^3 q1 r1 + 10 p1^2 r1^3, 
 8 p1^3 q1^2 + p1^2 p2 q1^2 + 30 p1^2 q1 r1^2 + 5 p1 r1^4, 
 25 p1^2 q1^2 r1 + 4 p1 p2 q1^2 r1 + 20 p1 q1 r1^3 + r1^5 + 
  p1 p2 q1^2 r2, 
 5 p1^2 q1^3 + 3 p1 p2 q1^3 + p2^2 q1^3 + 20 p1 q1^2 r1^2 + 
  6 p2 q1^2 r1^2 + 5 q1 r1^4 + 3 p2 q1^2 r1 r2 + p2 q1^2 r2^2, 
 8 p1 q1^3 r1 + 3 p2 q1^3 r1 + 4 q1^2 r1^3 + 2 p1 q1^3 r2 + 
  2 p2 q1^3 r2 + 3 q1^2 r1^2 r2 + 2 q1^2 r1 r2^2 + q1^2 r2^3}
```